# Question on Basic Proportionality

Tags: geometry

[image]

I'm looking to understand this homework problem which is already worked in the text but without explanation.
I understand that to show that 2 triangles are similar I would need to use either SSS, or SAS or AA.  When using SAS, I'd need to show that the 2 sides are proportional before I could conclude that the triangles are proportional.

Here I am given that the angle K is bisected.  It is not clear how that helps me conclude that the triangle KMN is similar to triangle KLN.  If I can show similarity, then I can see how the proportion would work.

I understand that KN is congrunt to KN by reflexive.  But, I don't see how this gives me SAS since I'm not able to show the sides are proportional.  The book immediately jumps to the assumption that the sides ARE proportional, but I don't see how I can conclude this if I saw this problem on a test.

Or, am I missing the point?  Why does the bisected angle help here at all?

Comment: You must apply the angle bisector theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this construction:

[image]

$ABC$ is similar to $ADE$

$\frac {AB}{BC} = \frac {AD}{DE}$

and $BC = BE$

so
$\frac {AB}{BE} = \frac {AD}{DE}$

The Angle bisector splits the opposite side into pieces that are proportional to the ratio of the adjacent sides of the triangle.

Comment: Thank you for this simple and VERY helpful proof .....for me it completely explains this!

Answer (score 0):

There a locus called *Apollonius Circle* with property $KN$ as a variable bisector of angle $MKL$ such that you always have ratio

$$ \dfrac {KM}{KL}=\dfrac {MN}{NL} $$ the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I will take the time to look up this Apollonius Circle and I'm sure this will add new insight.  Thank you for taking the time to answer.